# First Try at Gettin Grainy 

Tags: granular-synthesis

Hey Team,

I just made my first attempt at making a granular synth patch.

[soundcloud]g-a-harry/call-me-distant-and-ill-come[/soundcloud]

Apologies for the 1000 tons of reverb, but bare it sounded kinda harsh.

I'm trying to figure out how to make it a little more palatable without having to do too much processing after the fact.  So any advice/critique/suggestions/ideas would be most welcome.  Particularly with regards to non-reverb softening.

Comment: gettin grainy in the rainy!!

Comment: if you got access to max/msp go and try Robert Henke's Granulator Patch ( http://www.ableton.com/pages/max_for_live/granulator ). You can get very rich, smooth textures with it - without any reverb.

Comment: I'm actually working on my own patch right now, but I'll check it out. 

Comment: Status update??

Comment: Totally got sidetracked away from that one.  It was almost done too.  I'll have to re-visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interested in what you come up with…something I've been curious about but not tinkered with

Comment: Its actually a lot easier than I expecteds, to get it going anyway. Making it sound like what I want it to will be something else entirely. 

Comment: Right.  Thats what I kind of expected...

Answer (score 1):

hey, i'm just working on a polyphonic stereo grainsynth in max4live / maxMSP...

this is what it sounds like at the moment: [soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com/emsound/grainsynth-tests).
it's still beta (it already works the way i want it to, but i still have to clean up the code a little bit^^), and therefor not yet downloadable, but if you want to check it out, just send me a pm and i'll send you the patch...

feedback / ideas are appreciated too btw ;)

Comment: That's pretty cool! love the vocals

Comment: @manuel. I don't think this board has a pm system, which is weird. Send me an email, g.a.harry(at)gmx.com. 